# Convergence of minimum of a sequence of functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Consider functions $f_n, f$ from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. 
Suppose $f_n(y)$ converges pointwise to $f(y)$ for all $y$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. I would like to know under what conditions is the following statement correct.

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \min_y f_n(y) = \min_y f(y)$.

Comment: uniform convergence seems to be enough

Comment: could you give me a proof?

Comment: On compact intervals, you can use the following argument: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1823276/8157 HTH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uniform convergence implies the result. Let's first substitute $\min$ with $\inf$.

First take a $y_0$ such that $$f(y_0)\leq \inf _y f(y) +\epsilon$$

Then since $$ f(y_0)= \lim _n f_n(y_0) \geq \lim _n \inf_y f_n(y)$$

we get

$$\inf _y f(y) \geq \lim _n \inf_y f_n(y)\fbox{1}.$$

Now take $N$ such that $ |f_n(y) -f(y)| < \epsilon$ $\forall n \geq N$.

Pick $y_n$ such that $$ f_n(y_n)\leq \inf _y f_n(y) +\delta$$

This gives that $-\epsilon<f_n(y_n)-f(y_n)  < \epsilon  $ therefore
4
$$-\epsilon < \inf _y f_n(y) +\delta - f(y_n)\Rightarrow \inf_y f(y)\leq  f_n(y_n)-\epsilon < \inf _y f_n(y)   +\delta  $$

taking $n\rightarrow \infty$

We get $$\inf _y f(y) \leq \lim _n \inf_y f_n(y) \fbox{2}$$

So we conclude.

**Remark** Wecould have been more rigorous if in $\fbox {1}$ we had taken $\limsup$, and in $\fbox{2}$ $\liminf $ instead of $\lim$.

Comment: Is this fact and this proof valid also if I have only uniformly convergence on compact sets? Thanks!

Comment: @Gloria No, this does not generally hold. For instance one can take $f_n(x)= \frac{x}{n} 1_{|x| \leq n^2}(x)$

Comment: Do you know a reference for this useful result ?