# If $f_{n}\longrightarrow f$ is a uniformly convergent sequence in a compact topological group $G$, then $\min(f_{n})\longrightarrow\min(f)$

Tags: general-topology, uniform-convergence

Let $G$ be a compact topological space and $f_{n}$ a uniformly convergent sequence in $C(G,\mathbb{R})$. Let $f$ be the limit of  the $f_{n}$. I want to show that $\min(f_{n})\longrightarrow\min(f)$.

I've tried different approaches to this problem but I've only managed to prove that there exists a subsequence $f_{n_{k}}$ such that $\min(f_{n_{k}})\longrightarrow\min(f)$. If I could show that the whole sequence $\min(f_{n})$ has a limit then I would be pretty much done, but so far nothing has worked for me. I've read and tried to adapt the proofs in these two comments but some parts of the argument are hard to follow:

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1828540

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1823276

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where does the group structure com into play? How is $\min$ defined for an arbitrary topological group (which need not have an order relation)? I don't understand your question.

Comment: @Math1000 the functions $f_n$ go from $G$ to $\Bbb R$ and as $G$ is compact, $\min f_n$ is a well-defined real number. The order is from the reals.

Comment: @Math1000 I'm sorry, I meant compact topological space. I'm working in the framework of topological groups so I added unnecessary hypothesis.

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy You're right. You don't need the additional group structure. I meant topological space. I think your argument does it. It was way simpler than I thought, Thank you very much!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Oh, I missed  the part that $f_n$ is assumed to be in $C(G,\mathbb R)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is too elementary and does not require any theorem on topological groups.

Let $\epsilon >0$. Choose $n_0$ such that $|f_n(g)-f(g)| <\epsilon$ for all $g$ for  $n >n_0$. Let $a_n=\inf_{g\in G} f_n(g)$ and $a=\inf_{g \in G} f(g)$. For $n >n_0$ we have $f_n(g) <f(g)+\epsilon$ so $a_n < f(g)+\epsilon$. Since this is true for all $g$ we get $a_n \leq a+\epsilon$. Similarly we get $a \leq a_n+\epsilon$ for. $n >n_0$. Since minimum is same as infimum we are done.